# Maple : graphing an ellipse

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, maple

I want to draw an ellipse on maple, $x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1=0$ but I think I'm making a mistake :
$Gr1:=plot(x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1=0,x=-7..14,y=-7..14):$

$display(Gr1);$

But it says enven before my display line : Error, (in plot) unexpected options: [x^2+y^2+x+xy+y+1 = 0, x = -7 .. 15, y = -7 .. 15]
I am using maple 2015.

Answer (score 2):

```
with(plots)
implicitplot(x^2+x*y+y^2+x+y-1,x=-10..10,y=-10..10,gridrefine=5)
```

The ellipse you chose, $x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1=0$, has no real points.

Your new ellipse:

[image: ellipse]

Comment: @Aezir See the edit. And use `x*y`.